# iTunes Connect, Application Loader uploads app then iTunes connect emails that invalid binary

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing

I am submitting a new version of my app, so when I put the app in application loader it goes fine then ITC emails me:

> Dear Developer,
>
> Thank you for your recent binary submission for "(My App)" to the App Store. Unfortunately we discovered an issue with your binary that you will need to correct in order for your application to proceed to the review stage. The specific issue is outlined below:
>
> Invalid Signature - Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target.
>
> Once you have corrected the issue, please return to the application's version details page in the iTunes Connect Manage Your Applications module and click on the Ready to Submit Binary button. This will take you through the binary submission flow and return your application version status to Waiting for Upload. You can then use Application Loader to upload your new binary. If any other issues are found with your submission you will be contacted.
>
> Thanks,
>   The iTunes Connect Team

I have now tried at least 4 times but still the same.
Anyone know whats happening?

Answer (score 0):

### Your Distribution certificate is not correct.

I'm one of those users that absolutely *hates* when people just point me to Apple documentation. However, I was in your exact same predicament a few years ago, and it helped me. Go to the Apple developer portal and search for 'distribution certificate'. Up will come a nice long document about how to sign apps.

Print it out and read it. **Try to read the whole thing.**

About half way through you will go *AAAck! I can't stand any more Apple docs!*

When this happens, open up Xcode and Safari and try everything you have read. Refresh certificates. Regenerate them. Make new ones. Mess with popup menus in Xcode.

After each combination, try to submit. Eventually, you ***will*** find a winning combination. I promise.